# python subprocess.check_output not working on every cases

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm trying to automate some of my security network tasks to help me in my day-to-day job and came across the issue below.

I have the code:

```
OSNmapScanCommand="nmap -nvv -Pn -O --osscan-guess --defeat-rst-ratelimit " + IP + " | grep \"Device type:\" -A4 > "+ MyFile
subprocess.check_output(OSNmapScanCommand, cwd=CurrentHost, shell=True)
```

For some reasons it works fine on some hosts, but on some others I get nmap outputting text, which I believe triggers an error as only on those cases my script stops running:

```
adjust_timeouts2: packet supposedly had rtt of -161442 microseconds.  Ignoring time.
adjust_timeouts2: packet supposedly had rtt of -161442 microseconds.  Ignoring time.
adjust_timeouts2: packet supposedly had rtt of -1384846 microseconds.  Ignoring time.
adjust_timeouts2: packet supposedly had rtt of -1384846 microseconds.  Ignoring time.
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "nmap.py", line 152, in <module>
        subprocess.check_output(OSNmapScanCommand, cwd=CurrentHost, shell=True)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 219, in check_output
        raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'nmap -nvv -Pn -O --osscan-guess --defeat-rst-ratelimit xx.xx.xx.xx | grep "Device type:" -A4 > myfile.txt' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

I have been scripting a long script already using subprocess.check_output and subprocess.check_call without issue, but I'm stuck on this one.

Thanks for your help!

[Edit] If I run the nmap command separately, this is what I get:

```
adjust_timeouts2: packet supposedly had rtt of -164659 microseconds.  Ignoring time.
adjust_timeouts2: packet supposedly had rtt of -164659 microseconds.  Ignoring time.
adjust_timeouts2: packet supposedly had rtt of -1395479 microseconds.  Ignoring time.
adjust_timeouts2: packet supposedly had rtt of -1395479 microseconds.  Ignoring time.
adjust_timeouts2: packet supposedly had rtt of -1396430 microseconds.  Ignoring time.
adjust_timeouts2: packet supposedly had rtt of -1396430 microseconds.  Ignoring time.
adjust_timeouts2: packet supposedly had rtt of -1396454 microseconds.  Ignoring time.
adjust_timeouts2: packet supposedly had rtt of -1396454 microseconds.  Ignoring time.
adjust_timeouts2: packet supposedly had rtt of -90623 microseconds.  Ignoring time.
adjust_timeouts2: packet supposedly had rtt of -90623 microseconds.  Ignoring time.
Device type: general purpose|switch|printer|firewall|security-misc|WAP|remote management|specialized
Running (JUST GUESSING): Linux 2.6.X|2.4.X (95%), Extreme Networks ExtremeXOS 12.X (93%), Kyocera embedded (93%), Barracuda Networks embedded (93%), AVM embedded (90%), Linksys embedded (90%), Netgear embedded (90%), Dell embedded (90%)
OS CPE: cpe:/o:linux:linux_kernel:2.6 cpe:/o:extremenetworks:extremexos:12.5.4 cpe:/h:kyocera:cs-2560 cpe:/h:avm:fritz%21box_fon_wlan_7050 cpe:/h:linksys:wag200g cpe:/h:netgear:dg834gt cpe:/h:dell:remote_access_card:5 cpe:/o:linux:linux_kernel:2.4.21
Aggressive OS guesses: Linux 2.6.15 - 2.6.26 (likely embedded) (95%), Linux 2.6.16 (94%), Extreme Networks ExtremeXOS 12.5.4 (93%), Kyocera CopyStar CS-2560 printer (93%), Linux 2.6.15 (Ubuntu) (93%), Linux 2.6.26 (93%), Barracuda Web Application Firewall 460 (93%), Linux 2.6.32 (93%), Barracuda Web Filter (92%), Linux 2.6.22 (92%)
No exact OS matches for host (If you know what OS is running on it, see https://nmap.org/submit/ ).
```

So I think the error is comming from how I'm using subprocess.check_output ?

Comment: The command you ran returned a non-zero status, meaning it encountered an error and failed, thus, throwing that exception.

Comment: @RafaelBarros : I edited my initial post, the nmap command runs fine when launched separately.

Comment: Grep returns non zero if it doesn’t match anything - would that be expected?

Comment: @Guy: no, nmap always returns an OS